# Next.js - Language based metadata with next-intl

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-intl

The metadata can be declared before the page renderer function, with `next-intl`, you can get the locale from the passed params to the renderer function.

How can I declare the metadata based on the locale?

I tried:

`en.json`:

```
{
    "Index": {
        "page_title": "Homepage - SomePlatform"
    }
}
```

`tr.json`:

```
{
    "Index": {
        "page_title": "Ana Sayfa - SomePlatform"
    }
}
```

`page.js`

```js
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

const t = useTranslations('Index');

export const metadata = {
  title: t('page_title')
}
```

But it resulted in a Server Error:

```
Server Error
Error: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available
```

I'm using:

```bash
next@13.4.10
next-intl@^3.0.0-beta.9
```

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server';

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { locale }}) {
  const t = await getTranslations({ locale, namespace: 'Index'});

  return {
    title: t('page_title'),
  };
}
```

https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/environments/metadata-route-handlers#metadata-api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: getTranslations seems to be deprecated - now getTranslator is being used

Answer (score 0):

```js
export async function generateMetadata({ params }){
    // read route params then fetch data
    // get params from route
    const { locale } = params;

    // return an object
    return {
        title: locale === "tr" ? 'TR Title' : "EN Title",
        description: locale === "tr" ? 'TR Description' : "EN Description",
    };
}
```

This can be used as a temporary solution.

or

```js
export async function generateMetadata({ params }){
    const { locale } = params;
    const messages = (await import(`../../content/${locale}.json`)).default;

    // return an object
    return {
        title: messages.breadcrumbs.home.title,
        description: messages.breadcrumbs.home.description,
    };
}
```